# VS2017 15.4.2 - project file is not bound to source control after SSRS project upgrades

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, tfvc

Today I updated Visual Studio 2017 to 15.4.2 and found that the projects that come with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 15.4.0 preview were no longer available, a common occurrence following an update. I repaired the SSDT install to find the projects did not come back, I then re-installed it and the projects were now available.

Now when I open an existing solution that contains 19 reporting services projects I was prompted that they needed to be upgraded, I haven't had this prompt since using the preview on first release. I went ahead and upgrading all the projects, added a new report to a project and submitted changes to my TFVC repository in Team Services.

Now whenever I open this solution I am prompted with this for every project:

> The project file  is not bound to source control, but
>   the solution contains source control binding information for it. Do
>   you want to open the project using source control binding information
>   from the solution or open it as unbound and fix the solution file?

If I use the solution binding this works until I close the solution and then I'm prompted again for the same thing. If I choose to remove the solution bindings and bind them again via File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control once the solution is saved and closed I get the same prompt.

I've downloaded a specific version from my repository prior to the project upgrades and I'm just getting prompted to upgrading them which breaks the source control again.

As it stands my solution is unusable, is there a way to fix my solution/project files manually as the suggested fixes I've seen so far are not working.

Comment: This is not just SSRS projects that have been upgraded. This is an issue with SSDT in VS 2017. If you create an empty solution, add new SSRS report project, add to TFS, close, re-open the SLN, you will get the same error.

Comment: What if you map the TFVC repo to another directory and open the project again? And there has a similar question, that solved the problem by uninstall and re-install VS and SSDT https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e78e4ef2-1364-488d-82a0-197394c951ed/ssdt-1540-preview-source-control-provider-associated-with-this-solution-could-not-be-found?forum=ssdt.

Comment: I've tried mapping to another directory, reinstalling VS and SSDT and also a previous version of VS2017 but I'm always getting the same behavior now. I'm also frequently getting check out errors `The item ....rptproj.vspcc could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it`

Comment: Each time I open my solution and selecting "Use Solution Binding" for all my SSRS projects I'm finding that the project file is being checked out and showing as a pending change when nothing has, any suggestions on how to prevent this checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this for now by doing the following

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2017 15.4.2 and SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 15.4.0 preview
2. Install Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5
3. Install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 15.4.0 preview
4. Remove Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 1.17 in Extensions and Updates
5. Install Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 1.18 in Extensions and Updates

I've found that updating Visual Studio 2017 to 15.4.2 after this none of the business intelligence projects are available. Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 1.18 is listed in Extensions and Updates but I had to reinstall this to be able to open the projects.

Comment: How did you uninstall the VS 15.4.2 update? I don't see a way to uninstall any updates for VS 2017. Also, how did you remove the reporting services extenstions? I don't see this name under the VS Extension and Updates. I do have all the SSDT (15.4.0) tools checked when I installed SSDT and I do have 15.4.2 VS 2017.

Comment: I uninstalled the full VS 15.4.2 via the VS installer. I then installed 15.3.5 from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017. The 3 extensions were listed under installed after the SSDT preview installer. I found that installing Integration Services only via the preview installer after updating to 15.4.2 and then analysis/reporting services via extensions and updates works.

Comment: I uninstalled VS 2017 15.4.2 and then installed VS 2017 15.3.5 and then installed the SSDT 15.4.0.  When I go to VS 2017 --> Tools --> Extensions and Updates , I still don't see SSRS / Reporting Serivces. I also don't see Reporting in Control Panel --> Programs --> Program and Features. With VS 2017 15.3.5 it is still broken "The project file is not bound to source control".

Comment: If you are just wanting SSRS you could just install that from Extensions and Updates? Odd it's not appearing

Comment: After searching for the Extension using the Online option, it finally showed in the list. I removed it and then installed it again. All working now on VS 15.3.5. Thanks for the information.

Comment: A downgrade of Visual Studio is not needed anymore. Upgrading to 15.5.2 and install 1.20 of Microsoft Reporting Services Projects Extension fixes the issue. See answer by jaycer.

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps resolved this issue for me:

1. Update Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 to v15.5.2
2. Update Microsoft Reporting Services Projects to v1.20